# How to limit SQL-DML resource use

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

I have a single server running Oracle 11g and Server 2008r2 with 32GB of RAM and 2 quad core CPUs at 3Ghz (8 cores total, no HT). My disks consist of 4 10,000RPM SAS drives in RAID 10.

When I execute a DML statement to insert rows from another table and delete them, this can cap out the CPU on my box and lock up the DB and prevent new records from being written.

Is there a way to limit the amount of system resources or oracle resources that can be used by a SQL query?

Thank you

Comment: Unless you are running the express edition or you are using parallel DML, a single session would use at most 100% of one core.  That would leave 7 cores available for other sessions to use.  Are you certain that the bottleneck is on CPU?  What edition of the database are you using?

Comment: Single server with both Oracle *and* SQL Server?  How is that configured?

Comment: APC: Windows Server 2008r2, and Oracle 11g (11.2) Enterprise.

Comment: Justin Cave: I am executing some fairly simple DML: INSERT INTO ARCHIVE_MYTABLE SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE UNIX_DATE BETWEEN V_ST AND V_ET where V_ST and V_ET are unix_dates passed for the beginning and end of a month. This is immediately followed with a DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE UNIX_DATE BETWEEN V_ST AND V_ET. This statement can cause all 8 cores to cap at 100% with plenty of RAM and Disk I/Os to spare.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @JustinCave that it seems unlikely that one session can suck up all the CPU on a multi-core server.  Unless you have more than one database installed.

Anyway, from an Oracle perspective, your DBA can configure consumer groups and resource plans which control how sessions can use various resources, including CPU.    [Find our more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dbrm002.htm).

Resource management is a strategic approach, suitable for handling persistent resource allocation problems.  If you have an issue with a single query you would be better off tuning it.